# How do I check status code 204 (NO CONTENT) in Volley JSONObject request Android

Tags: android, android-volley, jsonobjectrequest, http-status-code-204

Looked around but couldn't find solution to this.
Checking status code via following code:

```
JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(URL, null,
                response -> {

                    Log.d("Response", response.toString(4));

                },error -> {

                NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;

                if (networkResponse != null) {
                    if (error.networkResponse.statusCode == 204) {
                       Toast.makeText(Customers.this, "No Content!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                       //This is where I want request to return when no content.
                    } 
                }else{ 
                   //Null Network Response, request returns in this section
                }
}
```

When I send 204 Status code from server, which is for NO_CONTENT, request returns in error section and with network response NULL so I can't check if it was NO_CONTENT error or internet issue or some other.

Let me know if anyone can help.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should check your statusCode in your response block.

Comment: @littlebear333 response block is not being called, error block is called.

Comment: Print the error message. I think there are some problems with your network or the url or the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was issue with server side logic. It worked after fixing that. Thanks everyone.